# Why doesn't .isascii() work on google colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am working on Windows 10 and Pycharm IDE.
Is there a reason that `.isascii()` does not work on google colab? When I try the snippet of code on google colab I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isascii'
```

If I try the same code on my IDE I'm getting `True`.

```
thisstr = "Hoho"
k = thisstr.isascii()
print(k)
```

Comment: I ran your code in Python console on my machine and got true, while Google Colab threw an error. So weird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The python version in Google Colab is 3.6 while `isascii` method is introduced in Python 3.7. Quoting from [What's new in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html):

> `str`, `bytes`, and `bytearray` gained support for the new isascii() method, which can be used to test if a string or bytes contain only the ASCII characters.